# QTableWidget: don't close editor when pressing Enter

Tags: qt, qtableview, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

I would like my `QTableWidget` to trigger the edition callbacks when pressing Enter while editing item BUT I would like the editor to remain activated – like it would just select all of the item’s content like when you start editing the cell.

What is the best way to do this?

Thanks for having a look here.

Comment: Best way - create your own editor, if standard behavior doesn't satisfy your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should modify the table's item delegate and use event filters to filter out Enter event and implement custom behavior:

```
class MyDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate {
public:
  MyDelegate(QObject* parent) : QStyledItemDelegate(parent) {}
  QWidget* createEditor(QWidget* parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem& option,
                        const QModelIndex& index) const {
    QWidget* editor = QStyledItemDelegate::createEditor(parent, option, index);
    editor->installEventFilter(const_cast<MyDelegate*>(this));
    return editor;
  }

  bool eventFilter(QObject* object, QEvent* event) {
    QWidget* editor = qobject_cast<QWidget*>(object);
    if (editor && event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress) {
      QKeyEvent* key_event = static_cast<QKeyEvent*>(event);
      if (key_event->key() == Qt::Key_Return) {
        emit commitData(editor); //save changes
        QLineEdit* line_edit = qobject_cast<QLineEdit*>(editor);
        if (line_edit) {
          line_edit->selectAll();
        }
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
};
```

Usage:

```
ui->tableWidget->setItemDelegate(new MyDelegate(this));
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and code, I’m pretty new to Qt delegates.

Answer (score 0):

PyQt5 code looks like this:

```
class GlyphCellItemDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def eventFilter(self, editor, event):
        if (event.type() == QEvent.KeyPress and event.key() == Qt.Key_Return):
            self.commitData.emit(editor)
            # Don't emit closeEditor, select contents instead
            editor.selectAll()
            return True
        return False
```